# Springboot placed application yaml files in resources/config/ folder, while running the JAR it is not able to find the resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My Project Structure

```
AssemblyProject
 |-src/main/java
 |-src/main/resources
   |-config
     |-application-prod.yml
     |-application.yml
     |-application-stage.yml
 |-build.gradle
```

I am able to generate JAR file.
and trying to execute below command from the JAR file location

```
java -jar assembly-services-1.0.0.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:config/ --spring.profiles.active=stage
```

Extracted JAR as well
[image]

I am getting below Error

```
14:43:15.924 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException: Property 'spring.profiles.active' imported from location 'class path resource [config/application-stage.yaml]' is invalid in a profile specific resource [origin: class path resource [config/application-stage.yaml] from assembly-services-1.0.0.jar - 38:13]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.lambda$throwOrWarn$1(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.throwOrWarn(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.checkForInvalidProperties(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:354)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.applyToEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:323)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:236)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at com.assembly.Application.main(Application.java:73)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

**Note**: I know this is repeated question, But I have literally gone through all past stackoverflow questions related to this topc, but sadly no luck !

Comment: Why is the file in the config directory?

Comment: Its the structure demanded from customer only. there is requirements of keeping separate config files in separate layered folders.

Comment: Where's the `application-stage.yml` located? I couldn't see it on your project structure.

Comment: Oh thats my mistake, I thought I have written in the question only. I am updating the question again. I do have in my project with that respective folder structure.

Comment: You have the property `spring.profiles.active` defined inside your `application-*.yaml` files, don't you? If you do then you need to remove it. That's the reason you're getting this error

Comment: @MarcosBarbero you are having egale eyes :) I found that in my stage properties I have default added below property
spring
  profiles:
    active: []
I am removing and checking it.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcosBarbero I can now able to see Spring logs. I want to know why adding blank profile killing start up activity ? what is the problem If I am keeping blank, since I am telling spring explicitly to load XXX Profile. It should work with previously as well.

Comment: I believe it's related to this very property, you either define all the profiles in a single `application.properties/yaml` or you have separated files. In your case it's kinda mixing both and the `ApplicationContext` just breaks.

Comment: Thank you @MarcosBarbero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I can see is you must have provided active profile in your `application-stage.properties` as well. You need to remove it. According to spring boot documentation:

> So in Spring Boot 2.4 we’re planning to make two significant changes
> to the way the properties and YAML files are loaded:
>
> Documents will be loaded in the order that they’re defined.
>
> Profiles can no longer be activated from profile specific documents.

If you still want to use legacy configuration you need to provide `spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true` to your `application.properties`

Comment: I have removed the blank properties for active .profile, this works for me.
If you can tell me is this creating conflict between runtime arguments and hard coding arguments ?

Comment: It is not conflicting but the profile property (i.e `spring.profiles.active`) is not part of the configuration property and spring boot does not recorgnize it anymore as per the new version of spring boot.

Comment: Thank you @hiren

Comment: @DnyaneshwarJadhav you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Accepted @hiren, :)